# Where can I find free sound effects for a game?

Tags: audio

Where can I find free sound effects for a game?

Comment: Apparently a number of people are willing to play...

Comment: http://www.lmgtfy.com/?q=free+sound+effects+for+a+game

Comment: I'd say "sound effects" are closer to "software" than "programming".

Comment: Also have a look at http://www.bfxr.net/

Comment: Visit http://freesoundsfx.com/  - you can download mp3 sound effects (320kb/s) available for commercial projects too. 

Link back is optional (this is not for webmaster). 
You can't share this sound (unless is part of your project and is not the main focus) but you can share the link to site.

Comment: you can use http://www.bfxr.net/ this tool for make awesome sounds.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

http://www.freesound.org/
Also, archive.org may have some stuff.

Answer (score 8):

[sfxr](http://www.cyd.liu.se/~tompe573/hp/project_sfxr.html) is a great tool if you want to generate vintage arcade sounds.  It can generate all sorts of cool laser, explosions & blip sounds.  You can generate random sounds or adjust existing ones until you get just what your looking for. There is Mac port as well called [cfxr](http://thirdcog.eu/apps/cfxr)

Happy tweaking :)

Comment: Link broken; I've found this which seems to be the author's page: http://www.drpetter.se/project_sfxr.html and a google code page: https://code.google.com/p/sfxr/

Answer (score 7):

- [Free Sound Effects and Royalty Free Sound Effects](http://www.partnersinrhyme.com/pir/PIRsfx.shtml)
- [Tintagel's Free Sound File Archive](http://freesoundfiles.tintagel.net/Audio/index.shtml) (dead link)
- [Copyright and Public Domain Music](http://www.pdinfo.com/link.php) (dead link)
- [Sounds Effects and Music](http://www.shambles.net/pages/school/SoundE/)
- [eHow - How to Find Public Domain Sound Effects](http://www.ehow.com/how_2059827_find-public-domain-sound-effects.html)

Essentially, you want to be searching for "public domain" sound effects - these are sound effects that are made for the intention of publicly sharing, i.e. they have no copyright and you can use them however you like. Those were just the top results for a Google search for "[public domain game sound effects](http://www.google.com/search?q=public+domain+game+sound+effects)".

Sorry to piggyback off Google here, but that's really your best bet; just keep exploring til you find what you need!

Answer (score 2):

I know that a lot of people use [Flashkit](http://www.flashkit.com/) for free sfx in Flash videos, at least.

Answer (score 2):

When Soundsnap went pro, I started using:

[freesfx.co.uk](http://www.freesfx.co.uk)

It's Creative Commons based and all sounds are free to use plus there are somthing like 1,500 sounds in there too currently. I have used several pro sites in the past and I must say that everything on this site is just as high quality.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you also this very nice website : http://www.lasonotheque.org/en/

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is regarded as an off-topic question. Instead of adding a late answer, it would be more useful to answer other more recent questions, where there will be more traffic to upvote good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of CC-licensed music and sound-effects on [Kongregate Collabs](http://www.kongregate.com/collabs/sounds).
Also, the free utility [sfxr](http://www.cyd.liu.se/~tompe573/hp/project_sfxr.html) and its Mac version [cfxr](http://thirdcog.eu/apps/cfxr) are terrific for quickly-generating game sounds.

Answer (score 1):

My honest advice is [buy a decent microphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphone) and [buy some cantelope](http://darksectorgame.blogspot.com/2007/03/vegetable-abuse.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you need voice acting for your game, [the guy who voiced Serious Sam is in need of cash and will do lines for $1/word](http://www.violencemedia.com/).

From his site:

> Hey there. My name is John J. Dick. You may know me as the voice actor who portrays 'Serious Sam'. I'm also working in Dallas as a strip club DJ. Barely making enough to keep my head above water. In fact, I'm not even doing that.
>
> Here's the skinny, I'm in debt... bad. $20,000 in credit card debt, bank overdrawn, behind on bills, etc. Got burglarized back in February, so I don't even have anything left to show for my debt. It's a long story how I got into this situation, if you're curious I'll tell you the details. Point being, though, I'm in a position where I'm desperate to pay my bills off in any way I can.

Answer (score 0):

- [freesound](http://www.freesound.org/)
- [Soundsnap](http://www.soundsnap.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[Free Sound Effects - SFXsource.com](http://www.sfxsource.com/free-sound-effects.cfm/)